# Unity project after migrating to Android Studio gives this error - java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/Keep.class

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

I am getting below error log:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   'app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.>
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/annotation/Keep.class

Here is the list of `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':chartboostSDK')
    compile project(':flurry_lib')
    compile project(':googleCloudMessaging_lib')
    compile project(':mainLibProj')
    compile project(':localytics_lib')
    compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1534')
    compile project(':unityandroidresources')
    compile project(':iAB_lib')
    compile project(':etcetera_lib')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/FlurryPlugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/FreshdeskPlugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/Prime31UnityActivity.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony-adapter-1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-bridge.jar')
    compile files('libs/apsalar.jar')
    compile files('libs/apsalarUnity3d.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost-adapter-1.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v5_4_3_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger.jar')
    compile files('libs/emojiplugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.61.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/nativex-adapter-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-annotations-23.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyunitywrapper.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-adapter-1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
}
```

Comment: don't put screenshots, add actual code.

Comment: Added the actual code.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes.. thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import the library as a `gradle` dependency like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
```

If you want to use `jar` then it seems like that it hasn't been properly built. So try to do something like this:

1. Unzip the `jar` file. (Simply change `.jar` extension to `.zip`
2. This will remove the duplicate files.
3. Recreate the `jar` using `jar cf xmlbeans.jar -C (path to unzipped folder) .` (Mind it, there is a dot in the end of command)
4. Use this regenerated `jar`

Comment: Great. Happy to help. :)

Comment: If possible, can you please explain what difference it makes ?

Comment: gradle automatically pull library from repository and builds it correctly. if you include jar then gradle doesn't build it. And in your case, jar which you had was **not** correctly built.